# Mongodb Architecture - How to design so I can quickly know what is available

Tags: performance, mongodb, database-design, database-schema, mongodb-query

I am working on architecting an app in MongoDB. The goal here is to have very fast reads but slow writes are okay.

Suppose I have three collections: `users`, `polls`, and `groups`. `users` create `polls` that are part of one `group` and `users` can join multiple `groups`. Finally `users` can answer `polls`.

Generally one user will have around 1-200 `groups` and each `group` can have 10,000+ `polls`. New polls are added constantly.

Current I have my data structure as so:

- `user` stores each `group_id` that the `user` belongs in.
- `poll` stores the `group_id` it belongs to and a list of `users` that has answered it.

I have a client that is logged in as an `user` - and thus knows all its `groups`. Is there an efficient way for me to find out if there are any unanswered `polls` for each `group` the `user` is in?

One solution is to just go through each `group` and run a query as so:

```
db.polls.find({
    group: group_id,
    users: {$nin: [user_id]}
})
```

This is not very efficient though if someone's got 200 groups. My other thought is to run the above once at the beginning of the app, then cache the number unanswered polls. Whenever the `user` answers a poll, this cached value is decremented until its some low number when the app will run the find operation again.

I realize this is a bit of an open-ended question which is sometimes frowned upon but not sure where else to ask it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If quickly identifying a user's unanswered polls is very high priority, you can do it by storing a document representing each pair `(user, poll)`:

```
{
    "user" : "Suzy Song",
    "poll" : "What shape Lego block are you? Take this poll and you'll never believe what happens next! Top 10 celebrity Lego block shapes explained!"
    "answered" : false
}
```

then you index on `{ "user" : 1, "answered" : 1 }` and query

```
db.poll_status.find({ "user" : "Suzy Song", "answered" : false })
db.poll_status.count({ "user" : "Suzy Song", "answered" : false })
```

With a user in 200 groups and each group having 10,000 polls, you might have 2,000,000 documents like the above.

Or you can summarize the number for each user or each `(user, group)` in another collection

```
{
    "user" : "Suzy Song",
    "group" : "Polar Bear Club",
    "unanswered_polls" : 999
}
```

and update appropriately every time a new poll is created in the group and when the user responds to a poll in the group.

Comment: Great response. The latter is similar to what I did. I store number of polls in group and number of answered polls in account and take the difference. Thanks!!